# Python writing to the wrong directory

Tags: python

For some reason, my python code is writing to the wrong directory.

I'm setting the output directory I want to write to here:

```
output_dir = os.path.join('..', '..', 'output_files', 'aws_instance_list', 'csv')
```

And I'm setting the file name here:

```
output_file = output_dir + 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today + '.csv'
```

But when I write the file out, I get a file in this location with this name:

```
..\..output_files\aws_instance_list\csvaws-instance-master-list-11-19-2019.csv
```

Instead, I want the file to be called:

```
..\..output_files\aws_instance_list\csv\aws-instance-master-list-11-19-2019.csv
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `output_file = output_dir + 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today + '.csv'` did you print out output dir? You should be able to spot what's wrong. This is also why make sure you keep constructing all paths using `os.path.join` or pathlib.

Comment: hint: `output_dir` does not contain a trailing "/".

Comment: @ParitoshSingh definitely second `pathlib`. `Path(output_dir) / f'aws-instance-master-list-{today}.csv')` reads very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.join` doesn't join a "\" to the end. Try this:

```
output_dir = os.path.join('..', '..', 'output_files', 'aws_instance_list', 'csv', '') # add '' to the end 

output_file = output_dir + 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today + '.csv'
```

Adding the `''` to the end of `os.path.join` will add an ending "\", which will separate your csv subdirectory and the filename.

Comment: This works, but you should not use + for joining a directory and a path.

output_file = os.path.join(output_dir. 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today + '.csv')
would be the better option.

In this case you could also remove `, ''` from the line aboce.

Comment: I totally agree, was just keeping it as close as possible to op's code

Answer (score 0):

```
output_file = os.path.join(
    output_dir, 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today + '.csv')
```

As @Paritosh Singh mentioned. Never use + to construct file paths.

Answer (score 0):

from [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) of `join` method:

> The return value is the concatenation of path and any members of *paths with exactly one directory separator (os.sep) following each non-empty part except the last, meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last part is empty.

This means `output_dir`'s last character is not `/` or `\`.

You may add it like:

`output_file = output_dir + '\\aws-instance-master-list-' + today + '.csv'` (Note the escape character, also see @gelonida's comment on why this is dangerous and you should avoid using it)

or better way is:

`output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today + '.csv')`

The last one is better because you don't need to deal with operating system dependent path naming conventions.

Comment: do not use '\\' for joining paths. As far as I know this will fail on linux.
'/' on the other hand works on both platforms.

But the real answer is to never use '+' to join path strings. just use os.path.join()

Comment: alternatively use os.path.sep, which will be `"\\"` or `"/"` respectively